# Start new activity when Url finishes loading

Tags: android, url, webview

I am loading a certain Url into a WebView . This is a login page and the user gets authenticated. When Authenticated he is shown a certain page. At this point I want to stop the Webview loading and start a new activity.

To do this, Iam catching the redirected url and comparing it with a String with my values if it matches then I stop the page loading. But the String Iam trying to compare with the url occurs twice. First when the page starts loading and second when the page complately finishes loading.I want to compare to the second one

But this does not start the new activity.

This is what I have tried:-

```
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);

        final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Details1.this, "Loading..", "Please wait!");



        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {





            private Object progress;

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if(progressBar!=null && progressBar.isShowing())
                {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
                url= view.getUrl();
                redirected= Uri.decode(url);

                /*AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Details1.this);

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage(redirected)
                        .setCancelable(false)

                        .setNegativeButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();*/


                if(redirected!=null && redirected.contains(endpointHost+"/AuthorizeDevice/index/"+deviceId))

                {
                    Utility.ProgressDialogFragment progDialog = new Utility.ProgressDialogFragment();
                    progDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Wait");
                    myWebView.stopLoading();



                    String authorizationContentString =  AuthenticateDeviceEndPoint+ "?encodedAccountName=" + encodedAccountName + "&deviceId=" + deviceId + "&hostUrl=" + hostUrl;
                    authorizationContentString =authorizationContentString.replace("|", "%7C");

                    //UserInformation userInfo;
                     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                     Object register;
                    try 
                    {
                        //userInfo 
                    //  String responseData= new AuthenticateDevice(Details1.this,myprogressDialog).execute(authorizationContentString).get();
                        String responseData = new AuthenticateDevice(Details1.this, progDialog).execute(authorizationContentString).get();
                        register = parser.parse(responseData);
                        org.json.simple.JSONObject authDevice = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) register;

                        //Convert Json objects to strings

                        usersname  = (String) authDevice.get("FirstName");



                        AuthenticationInformation authInfo = new AuthenticationInformation(Details1.this);
                        authInfo.SetUserInformation(username );



                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (ExecutionException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Details1.this, Home.class);

                    myIntent.putExtra("UsersName", usersname);



                    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();
                    }



            }


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);


                return true;

            }
```

Comment: Try Logging the onPageFinished method. Then login and see when the log method is fired. If it's firing at the place you want, then you know where the problem is

Comment: Try to loadUrl after setting the webViewClient.

Comment: @Abdullah is there a way I can get the last redirected url when the page finally finishes loading and then start a new activity?

Comment: @Sripathi not working.

Comment: @Abdullah actually the String Iam trying to compare with the url occurs twice. First when the page starts loading and second when the page complately finishes loading.I want to compare to the second one

Comment: Are you getting response from the server? Have you checked that by printing the username or by debugging? Whats happening after requesting the server?

Comment: @Sripathi I get a 400 status code

Comment: @user3627247 Thats the problem, there might be an exception and its handled by the catch(). Try to comment the try catch block and run for a verification. If the activity starts then you can confirm that the problem is in the server request. I assumed that the problem is in request only.